# Absolute-Normal convergence of a sum

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have a sum which is normal convergent and I know the limit-function of the sum, does it implies that the sum of the absolute values of each term converges to the absolute value of the function?

Comment: the sum is a Fourier series and by the theorem of Dirichlet I know it converges normally to a certain function, but Im looking for the value of the sum of the absolute term of this series

Comment: It has absolutely no reason to converge to the absolute value of the sum, since $\lvert x+y\rvert\neq\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert$ in general.

Comment: I understand, so im still stuck.